# Custom word wrapping with TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, word-wrap

I have a multi-line textbox in my WinForms application, I set the `WordWrap` property to `true`.

But as you can see, when I set the `Text` property to the following string, the line breaks at '-' character of `ORD-082619/1023`.

```
myTextBox.Text = "ORD-082619/1020, ORD-082619/1021, ORD-082619/1022, ORD-082619/1023";
```

[image]

Is there any way to wrap the text as following image?
[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have access to the width of the textbox, so you can do a simple algorithm - `split by width` -> `from first line to last` -> `take part after the last comma, remove it from this line, add it to beginning of next line (if next line is empty, add a new line` -> continue till done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the regular hyphens with [non-breaking hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm):

```
myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.Replace("-", "\u2011");
```

[image]

This will of course only work if you don't have any of those before and need to know which was which, (in which case you can keep the original version somewhere, maybe in the Tag ;-)